# How to read a partitioned file using org.apache.spark.sql.json?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with more than 400,000 Partitions in AWS EMR. The data resides on AWS S3. Here each Partition is a Directory with 1 gz file which holds a Json Array.

So I am trying to use `org.apache.spark.sql.json` to create the table hoping that it will automatically parse the array and I can extract the data easily.

But the following commands fails. I have the `data.json.gz` or `data.json` files in `s3://my/test/data/partition=1987`

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `jsonArrData` STRING
, `partitionKey` INT )
USING org.apache.spark.sql.json
PARTITIONED BY (`partitionKey`)
LOCATION 's3://my/test/data/';

msck repair table testTable;
```

Comment: To start with you should not include partitioned column `partitionKey` as part of your table attributes.  Hive automatically includes it when it sees `partitioned by` clause.

Comment: Hi Bala, Yes. When defining tables in `spark-sql` shell `using org.apache.spark.sql.json` the shell complained that partition key is not in the in Table Attributes. Usually when defining tables in hive I have not included partition key in the in table Attributes.